# Display a react native component in a fixed screen position no matter what

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I would like to place a component, in this case a simple text app version number that is clickable and will force a version refresh, on the screen of a react native app.  I would like this to be visible no matter what platform the app is running on (iOS/Android/device/simulator/react-native-web), and no matter what else happens on the screen in the app.  If there are other things displayed, I'd like this component to display on top of them.  I have not been able to do this.

(Aside: This is for debugging, as I have not found that the Expo system reliably reloads and presents the current version of the app.  If someone would like to comment with a solution to this, great).

I've tried many things, for example, including the component below in the main app.js file.  In this case, it will display for all screens on iOS simulator, but not on Android device.  From other posts, I understand that this may have to do with Android limitations.

Thank you for your help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'
import { Updates } from 'expo';

export default class AppVersion1 extends Component {
    _onPressButton = ()=> {
        AppConsole.log('Pressed reload')
        Updates.reload()
    }

    render(){

        return(<View style={styles.appVersionPosition}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
            <Text
                style={styles.appversion}
                onPress={this.reload}
            >
                <Ionicons name="md-refresh" /> Beta043</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>)}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    appversion: {
        color:'white',
        backgroundColor:'#68a0cf',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize:10,
        zIndex: 99999
    },
    appVersionPosition: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '7%',
        left: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
        zIndex: 99999
    }
})
```

Comment: What we have done is using a appversion parameter in headers. So for each http request it will check the app version and if the appversion is below the latest app version then it will force redirect to playstore using `Linking` . So you can implement this strategy if it fits in your case.

Comment: You can try something like modals or portals, contents that are out of main context and can always be shown, for example: https://github.com/cloudflare/react-gateway